# Use a different transition in Durandal for some views

Tags: durandal, hottowel

I develop a SPA thanks to Durandal. In this template we can define a transition which is used when navigating from one page to another. The transition style is defined ones for all in the main module and is used for all the transitions.

I wonder if it is possible to use a different transition for some specific views?

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

## I wonder if it is possible to use a different transition for some specific views?

Yes, you can.  [I created a transition helper](https://gist.github.com/evanlarsen/4799019) which is just a custom transition that uses [Animate.css](http://daneden.me/animate/) open source library.

So, if you look at the `doTrans` method where the transition magic happens it is passed 3 arguments: `parent`, `newChild`, `settings`.

`parent` and `newChild` are references to the html views which you use to animate.

I think the `settings` object is what your looking for.. because that contains the reference to your viewmodel which is bound to your new view, under `settings.model` property.

So, you could create your own custom transition and inspect `settings.model` for some property on your new viewmodel which will decide how you should animate the next view in.

I hope I was able to explain this clearly enough. If not then let me know and I'll create a example of this for you.

Comment: Evan - +1 for the gist post in your answer.  I had seen it before (maybe in Google groups), but lost track of it. :)

Comment: @Evan: thanks for your answer I didn't have time to check it. Can you create a little example to show me how to change default transition for some specific views? Let's say I have the following link: `<a data-bind="attr: { href: hash }, html: name"></a>` Is it possible to add a 'transition' binding on this link to force a specific transition? Thanks anyway.